# How to get x and y co-ordinates of image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a project where I need click photo from the app and after that allow user to select particular area of image and add product there. After that whenever user tap on that particular area it should redirect to different page with product details and show that particular selected part as cropped image in new page. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can wrap with GestureDetector and get local position

Comment: you would need an image size (I mean physical size measured in pixels) - otherwise you cannot tell what is the scaling factor of the image widget

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.